# Error al usar STUFF en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una consulta y quiero agrupar datos de una columna en fila, separados por coma, a través de ejemplos he podido armar la siguiente consulta, pero al ejecutarlo me sale **The multi-part identifier "arr_inventario_sal.ains_folio" could not be bound**

```
SELECT  arr_inventario_sal.ains_folio,
          STUFF((SELECT ', ' + arr_inventario_sal.ains_num_serie AS Expr1
          FROM arr_inventario_sal INNER JOIN
          mov_inventario ON arr_inventario_sal.ains_folio = mov_inventario.inv_folio
  WHERE        (mov_inventario.inv_tip_doc_ref = 'FAC') AND (mov_inventario.inv_pto_vta = 'VIC') AND (mov_inventario.inv_fol_doc_ref = 134990) FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS SERIE
```

AL quitar **arr_inventario_sal.ains_folio,** me arroja los datos, pero necesito visualizar más columnas.

```
SELECT        STUFF
((SELECT ', ' + arr_inventario_sal.ains_num_serie AS Expr1
 FROM arr_inventario_sal INNER JOIN
 mov_inventario ON arr_inventario_sal.ains_folio = mov_inventario.inv_folio
 WHERE        (mov_inventario.inv_tip_doc_ref = 'FAC') AND (mov_inventario.inv_pto_vta = 'VIC') AND (mov_inventario.inv_fol_doc_ref = 134990) FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS SERIE
```

¿Alguna sugerencia para poder realizar mi consulta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Está sucediendo porque tratas de elegir una columna que no está en tu subconsulta (que tienes para hacer el stuff)

Como no estoy muy empapada sobre el resultado final de tu consulta, te dejo lo que entiendo debería ser

```
SELECT  arr_inventario_sal.ains_folio, 
        STUFF(( SELECT ', ' + arr_inventario_sal.ains_num_serie AS Expr1
                FROM arr_inventario_sal 
                INNER JOIN mov_inventario 
                   ON arr_inventario_sal.ains_folio = mov_inventario.inv_folio 
                WHERE (mov_inventario.inv_tip_doc_ref = 'FAC') 
                  AND (mov_inventario.inv_pto_vta = 'VIC') 
                  AND (mov_inventario.inv_fol_doc_ref = 134990) 
                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS SERIE
FROM arr_inventario_sal 
INNER JOIN mov_inventario 
    ON arr_inventario_sal.ains_folio = mov_inventario.inv_folio 
WHERE (mov_inventario.inv_tip_doc_ref = 'FAC') 
    AND (mov_inventario.inv_pto_vta = 'VIC') 
    AND (mov_inventario.inv_fol_doc_ref = 134990)
```

Comment: Gracias !! Me resuelve la duda, solo que una pregunta, la idea es que yo agrupara en una sola fila los datos, ya que de acuerdo a este resultado https://ibb.co/jbY7Dc solo se repiten las columnas, no se si eso se pueda hacer o yo tengo un concepto equivocado de stuff.

Comment: Puedes marcar entonces mi respuesta como respondida.Ayuda a otras personas a resolver sus dudas sabiendo que es la respuesta correcta.
Sobre tu duda creo que lo quieres es un Pivot,busca documentación al respecto y me dejas saber cualquier cosa